# Delphi Rio 10.3.2: remove file from a ZIP file

Tags: delphi, zip, compression

How would I remove a file from inside a ZIP file? I've tried various libraries/components so far with none succeeding:

Delphi's TZip: no support for removing files
KAzip: doesn't work in 10.3
Jcl (jedi): corrupt archive after closing it
Abbrevia: doesn't work in 10.3 (corrupt file)

Is there anything I can use with full source code and no external DLLs? (other than fully unpacking and repacking with TZip)

Comment: ZipForge has an [example](http://www.componentace.com/delete-file-from-zip-in-delphi.htm).

Comment: I noticed at least Abbrevia3 has a 'DeleteFiles' method in the manual which should work (it mentions saving the zip after such an operation). So you might want to show your code for Abbrevia at least vs just saying corrupt file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up making my own proc (for my own custom library).

tf = TFileStream with the zip
cSize = compressed file size

It's only good for a single file deletion.

```
procedure RemoveFile(name: string);
Var a,b: NativeInt;
   tm: TMemoryStream;
   RemovedSize,c: Cardinal;
const szChar = sizeof(AnsiChar);
begin

  // Locate File
  for a := Low(FileHeaders) to High(FileHeaders) do
   if CompareText(FileHeaders[a].fileName, name) = 0 then break;
  if a > High(FileHeaders) then Exit; // not found

  tm := TMemoryStream.Create;
  tf.Seek32(0, soBeginning);

  // copy up to the file to be removed
  tm.CopyFrom(tf, CentralDirs[a].headerOffset);

  // skip the file
  With FileHeaders[a] do
   RemovedSize := 30 + filenameLength + extraFieldLength + cSize;
  tf.Seek32(RemovedSize, soCurrent); // seek forward

  // update offsets for the next files
  for b := a+1 to High(FileHeaders) do
   Dec(CentralDirs[b].headerOffset, RemovedSize);

  // copy rest of the files
  c := 0;
  for b := a+1 to High(FileHeaders) do
  With FileHeaders[b] do
   Inc(c, 30 + filenameLength + extraFieldLength + cSize);

  tm.CopyFrom(tf, c);

  EOCD.centralDirOffset := tm.Position;

  // write Dir headers
  for c := Low(CentralDirs) to High(CentralDirs) do begin
    // skip removed file
    if c = a then Continue;
    With CentralDirs[c] do begin
      tm.Write(CentralDirs[c], 46);
      tm.Write(Pointer( CentralDirs[c].fileName )^,    szChar * CentralDirs[c].filenameLength);
      tm.Write(Pointer( CentralDirs[c].extraField )^,  szChar * CentralDirs[c].extraFieldLength);
      tm.Write(Pointer( CentralDirs[c].fileComment )^, szChar * CentralDirs[c].fileCommentLength);
    end;
  end;

  // Update EOCD data, copy
  With CentralDirs[a] do
   Dec(EOCD.centralDirSize, 46 + filenameLength + extraFieldLength + fileCommentLength);
  Dec(EOCD.numRecordsOnDisk);
  Dec(EOCD.numRecords);
  tm.Write(EOCD, 22);
  tm.Write(Pointer( EOCD.comment )^, szChar * EOCD.commentLength );
  tm.SaveToFile('test.zip');
  tm.Free;
end;
```

Comment: This is terribly inefficient, reading the entire zip file into memory, just to write it out again, save the removed file. Also, you have to start using try/finally.

Comment: How else would you do it? you have to shift the file content down after removing the file. For my use case it does the job, working on a ~60MB file, no need to copy/write by blocks.

Comment: So shift the file content down. If it is a huge file then your way could end up with a vast amount of needless copying. And you have to load the entire ZIP file into memory which is wasteful.

Comment: That's what I'm doing already: 1) Copy the original file up to offset of the file to be removed 2) copy the rest of the file from that point to the start of Central Dirs 3) update Central Dirs headers with new file offsets 4) write the modified Central Dirs (small data) 5) update EOCD

Comment: You don't need to copy up the first file. That content is unchanged. And you don't need to load the entire file into memory.

Comment: I'm saving the output to a separate zip, so I need to copy the prior files.

Comment: This code will most likely break files with ZIP64 data, signatures, spannings, as well as ZIP bombs and likewise. Do not use this on ZIP files you haven't created yourself!